# Upgrading to Grails 3.0.14 leads to CLI error

Tags: grails

I have been using Groovy 2.4.5 and Grails 3.0.8 installed via SDK, Java 1.8.0_45 on Mac OS 10.11.

When I install Grails 3.0.14 and change my grails properties file to use it, I get:

```
$ grails run-app

java.lang.RuntimeException: conversion of null to java.util.Map not implemented
  at org.grails.config.CodeGenConfig.convertToOtherTypes(CodeGenConfig.groovy:201)
  at org.grails.config.CodeGenConfig.convertToType(CodeGenConfig.groovy:196)
  at org.grails.config.CodeGenConfig.getProperty(CodeGenConfig.groovy:252)
  at org.grails.config.CodeGenConfig.loadYml(CodeGenConfig.groovy:133)
  at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.loadApplicationConfig(GrailsCli.groovy:455)
  at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:241)
  at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:153)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: conversion of null to java.util.Map not implemented
```

Any ideas how to fix this or what the underlying issue is?

Comment: when do you get this error?

Comment: @droggo when typing grails run-app

Comment: If you look into the source - https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/3.0.x/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/org/grails/config/CodeGenConfig.groovy it seems that Grails is not able to get variable `"environments.${envName}"` from `yml` file. This seems like a bug which should be reported but workaround could to be define some config for your environment in yml

Comment: per droggo's suggestion, adding a variable to the development section of application.yml worked
```environments:
    development:
      makeItWork: true
```

Comment: the issue https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9798 has been created.  Thx for the work around